# Why won't MiKTeX load some packages?

Tags: packages

I am using the latest versions of MiKTeX and Texmaker.  MiKTeX won't load revtex4-1 and aastex61, both of which are standard  class packages.  Any suggestions for what to do?

Comment: revtex4-1 is obsolete, the current version is revtex4-2, so miktex no longer packages it.

Answer (score 1):

The package versions you are trying to install may be outdated. You can download packages manually through MiKTeX Console in "Packages" folder, so it will just download the latest version.

Comment: revtex4-1 is still listed by CTAN.  Also, MiKTeX won't load aastex, which is also listed by CTAN and as far as I know is not obsolete.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: revtex4-1 on CTAN: "This is an old version of revtex, and is kept as a courtesy to users having difficulty with the incompatibility of that latest version." Load `revtex` instead, which is at version 4.2e. aastex is part of MikTek and TexLive: what error message do you get when you try to load it? In either case,  package can be downloaded manually.

Comment: When I try to use MiKTeX Console to get updates and packages, I am asked for proxy authentication.  I put in the username for my wifi and internet and my password for my computer, but the computer won't connect with the MiKTeX site.  Apparently, I don't understand what the proxy authorization is all about.  Any help would be appreciated.  I would add that the explanation about revtex4-1 being obsolete makes sense, but revtex4-1 is sitting right there in the CTAN package repository with no cautions about loading it.  Moreover, MiKTeX won't load aastex, which as far as I know is not obsolete.